# What is the correct way to fix bundler not finding compatible versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

I have an old rails 3 application which I want to update to rails 4 at the moment. I removed the Gemfile.lock manually and changed the Gemfile to require rails in version "4.0.0" before running a fresh "bundle install". I was getting several messages that bundler was not able to find compatible versions.

I am using ruby 2.0.0 here installed with rvm on a linux system.

I installed rails 4.0.0 manually using

gem install rails -v 4.0.0

And then I tried again with

bundle install

This is one example of the messages that pop up:

```rb
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    activerecord-import (~> 0.4.1) was resolved to 0.4.1, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 3.0)

    authlogic (~> 3.3.0) was resolved to 3.3.0, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 3.2)

    delayed_job_active_record (~> 4.0.0) was resolved to 4.0.3, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 3.0, < 5.0)

    rails (= 4.0.0) was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
      activerecord (= 4.0.0)
```

This is my Gemfile:

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# the rails framework: September 14, 2016 
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# the postgres db connector
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.0'

# a templating engine for html
gem 'haml', '~> 3.1.7'

# authentication solution
gem 'authlogic', '~> 3.3.0'

# role-based authorization system
gem 'acl9', '~> 0.12.1'

# helper methods for rails 3 models
gem 'dynamic_form', '~> 1.1.4'

# upload management for active record
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.2.2'

# tag a single model on several contexts
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 2.4.1'

# read and write spreadsheet documents
gem 'spreadsheet', '0.9.7'

# active record backend for Delayed::Job
gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '~> 4.0.0'

# wrap ruby scripts executed as deamon
gem 'daemons', '~> 1.1.9'

# writing and deploying cron jobs
gem 'whenever', '~> 0.8.2', require: false

# bulk inserting data using active record
gem 'activerecord-import', '~> 0.4.1'

# named scoples for postgres fulltext search
gem 'pg_search', '~> 0.5.7'

# jQuery and the jQuery-ujs driver for your Rails
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.3'

# jQuery UI's JavaScript, CSS, and image files
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 3.0.1'

# paginated queries with Active Record
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.5'

# group :production do
# performance management system
# gem 'newrelic_rpm'
# end

# Profiling toolkit
# gem 'rack-mini-profiler', :group => :development

group :test, :development do
  # unit testing framework
  gem 'test-unit', '~> 2.5.4'

  # process manager
  gem 'foreman', '~> 0.61.0'

  # code profiler
  # gem 'ruby-prof'

  # bindings for the GNOME Libxml2
  gem 'libxml-ruby', '~> 2.4.0'

  # wrapper for Linux inotify
  gem 'rb-inotify', '~> 0.9.1'

  # web server
  gem 'thin', '~> 1.5.0'

  # gem 'debugger'
  gem 'better_errors', '~> 0.3.2'

  # retrieve the binding of a method's caller
  gem 'binding_of_caller', '~> 0.8.0'

  # hosted test coverage service (badge)
  gem 'coveralls', '~> 0.8.23', require: false
  # gem 'codecov', :require => false, :group => :test
end

group :assets do
  # sass adapter
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'

  # coffee script adapter
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # call java script code and manipulate java script
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  # uglifier minifies java script
  gem 'uglifier', '~> 2.7.2'
end

group :tools do
  # code formatter
  gem 'rubocop', require: false

  # report vulnerable gems
  gem 'gemsurance', '~> 0.9.0'

  # handle events on file system modifications
  gem 'guard', '~> 1.6.1'

  # automatically run your tests on file modification
  gem 'guard-test', '~> 0.7.0'

  # html parser
  gem 'hpricot', '~> 0.8.6'

  # ruby parser written in pure ruby
  gem 'ruby_parser', '~> 3.1.2'
end
```

Due to the manual install of rails 4 I have activerecord in version 4.0.0 in my gems available. Why does it come up with that message? From my interpretation of the listed activerecord versions the dependency should be fulfilled with version 4.0.0? It is in the listed range between 3.0 and less than 5.

Comment: You definitely need to remove the group :assets do block.  See https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0.  Can you do that and then retry?

Comment: Thanks. I Fixed it now by updating the gems one after the other until it could resolve the bundle successfully. I guess that was not the most minimalistic approach, but the best I could think of.